# How to efficiently sort a list of objects in python by attribute

Tags: python, sorting, oop, attr

there might be a question with a similar title, but it does not help.

I am programming a dictionary (english, german) and my aim is now, to sort the cache(a list of all vocab-objects) alphabetically.
Each attribute of the class *vocab* is a list, whereby the first element/word in the list the most important one is and therefore the word you use to sort.

Here is a working minimal version:

```
class vocab:

    def __init__(self, english, german, context, box=0):
        """ self.eng/ger/con supposed to be lists"""
        self.eng = english
        self.ger = german
        self.con = context

    def present(self):
        return "English: {}\n\nGerman: {}\n\nExample: {}\n{}\n".format(self.eng,self.ger,self.con,"-"*20)
    #...


class dictionary:

    def __init__(self, Cache=[]):
        self.cache = Cache

    def sort_cache(self, sortby="eng"):
        """sort cache alphabetically (default = english)"""
        #list with sorted items
        #  -->item: (word used to sort, related vocObject)
        sort_cache = sorted([(getattr(voc,sortby),voc) for voc in self.cache])

        self.cache = [item[1] for item in sort_cache]

    def show_cache(self):
        """ print all vocabs from self.cache"""
        out = ""
        for voc in self.cache:
            out += voc.present()
        return out
    #...

#e.g.
voc1 = vocab(["to run"],["rennen","laufen"],["Run Forest! Run!!"])
voc2 = vocab(["to hide"],["(sich) verstecken","(etw.) verbergen"],["R u hidin sth bro?"])
voc3 = vocab(["anything"],["irgendwas"],["Anything ding ding"])
voc4 = vocab(["example","instance","sample"],["Beispiel"],["sample"])

MAIN_DIC = dictionary([voc1,voc2,voc3,voc4])

print MAIN_DIC.show_cache() #-->prints vocabs in order: to run, to hide, anything, example
                            #                           (voc1), (voc2) ,  (voc3) , (voc4)
MAIN_DIC.sort_cache()

print MAIN_DIC.show_cache() #-->prints vocabs in wanted order: anything, example, to hide, to run
                            #                                   (voc3) , (voc4) , (voc2) , (voc1)
```

Since I am creating an entirely new cache in my sort_cache method ,I wondered what a more efficient way would look like. I'm sure there is one.

For example. I would reckon that it would be more efficient(save time), to only sort the elements in *self.cache* without creating any copy etc..

Comment: More efficient in space or time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the "decorate-sort-undecorate" pattern:

```
    sort_cache = sorted([(getattr(voc,sortby),voc) for voc in self.cache])
    self.cache = [item[1] for item in sort_cache]
```

It was a preferred approach to sorting in Python for many years.  It has been replaced by built-in support in the `sort` and `sorted` functions:

```
self.cache = sorted(self.cache, key=lambda item: getattr(item, sortby))
```

Or

```
self.cache.sort(key=lambda item: getattr(item, sortby))
```

You may also want to consider maintaining `self.cache` in sorted order (by inserting things in the correct position in the first place - see the bisect module for help with this), thus amortizing the cost of sorting across your insertions (which may be more expensive overall but less expensive on any individual operation).

Also note that:

```
def __init__(self, Cache=[]):
```

gives you a *single* *shared* cache list across all `dictionary` instances that use this default.  Mutable default values is typically not what you want in Python.

Comment: what would be a better way instead of  `def __init__(self,Cache=[])` ?

Comment: Make the default `None`, check for that inside `__init__` and create a new list at that point if necessray.